# Update Table with xlsx file in DataEditR

Tags: r, shiny

I have some interactive datatable, `output-1`.
I want this table to have some default data when the app is started. In this case it is called `preiondat`. This data then should be overwritten when a file is uploaded. So I assign the preiondat to reactiveValues, `iondat` and when the user uploads a file it works correctly and the table is updated. However, I would like to have a table that is editable, so I try to display the data using DataEditR. But now the data no longer updates from the default data to the imported data, it just takes the preiondat and calls it a day. Is there anyway to update the DataEditR table using reactiveValues like a regular datatable?

Thank you

```
    library(DataEditR)
library(shiny)

# define UI for application
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # imported data
  dataInputUI("input1"),
  dataOutputUI("output-1"),
  dataEditUI("edit-1")
  )

# define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

  
  preiondat<-data.frame(name=c("CHLORIDE", "SULFATE", "BICARBONATE", "NITRATE", "PFOA"),
                        mw=c(34.95, 96.06, 12, 14, 414.07),
                        KxA=c(1, 0.028, 0.37, 13, 2500),
                        valence=c(1, 2, 1, 1, 1),
                        kL=c(1, 0.00021, 0.00021, 0.00021, 0.00021),
                        Ds=c(1, 0.0000002, 0.0000002, 0.0000002, 0.0000002))
  
  iondat<-reactiveValues(dat=preiondat)
  
  observe({
    file <- input$input1
    ext <- tools::file_ext(file$datapath)
    
    req(file)
    validate(need(input$file1$type == "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", "Please select xlsx"))
    
    ions<-read_xlsx(file$datapath, sheet=2)
    
    iondat$dat<-ions
  })
  
  # imported data
  data_to_edit <- dataInputServer("input1")
  data_edit <- dataEditServer("edit-1", data = data_to_edit)
  dataOutputServer("output-1", data=iondat$dat)

}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```